# How to make the memory card (SD) from digital camera to start automatically (enable Auto Run )?

Tags: windows-7, camera, sd-card, autorun

When I insert the memory card from my digital camera I want to start Autorun becouse I want to start copying the pictures automatically just like when I plug the USB-cable from the camera.Is there a trick to make the autorun for the sd-card to auto start?

p.s. I use Windows 7 on HP 4510s

Answer (score 2):

not familiar with this model, but i suppose the culprit is some HP memory card management software that is controlling the card reader in your printer and not Windows, you may disable this program (e.g. via [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)).

i suppose Autostart is not disabled globally as it kicks in when you connect the camera via USB.

Comment: did your sd-card start automatically?

Comment: i'm using a a little gadget like this and Autostart works just fine for all my SD(HC) cards.

Comment: but I use all usb ports every day and I want to use the memory cards port just like my old Sony Vaio laptop.This was not a problem on the Vaio

Comment: as i said, there might my some HP Card Reader management software controlling card reader. can you post a screenshot of your task manager with all running processes?

Comment: here is it:
http://i568.photobucket.com/albums/ss127/ZlateWay/Capture.jpg

and there is 3 more processes:
ccc.exe --> Catalyst Control Center:Host Application;
BTTray.exe --> Bluetooth Tray Application;
atieclxx.exe

Comment: the only entry i can see there for which i can only find little information (other than it is a HP program) is HPQToaster.exe, use Autoruns (from the link in my answer) and disable this program (don't delete it, just disable it) and restart the computer.

Comment: unless Autorun is indeed blocked for security reasons by your Firewall (Online Armor) or AV software (NOD32) ... but i doubt it, that would affect the USB ports as well.

Comment: there is no way to disable this HPQToaster.exe. I tried with Autoruns, msconfig and TuneUp Utilities and there is no process,service or startup named like that... I suppose that I must go to My Computer when I put the sd card in my laptop :P

Comment: well, there is always a way, the location is something like C:\Program
Files\HPQ\shared\HpqToaster.exe, you can use LockHunter to see what is locking it and move it to the recycle bin ... at the next start you'll find out from an error message what is calling the file :) note: do this at your OWN risk!

Comment: ok. thanks anyway for your time and i will search for this annoying problem.
Thanks again :)

Comment: you're more than welcome, keep us posted if you find the culprit. :)